# Regarding Customer Journey Mapping(CJM), can we make CJM's of same persona with different scenarios?

Tags: customer-experience

While making CJMs, can we choose them like:

- Persona 1 | Scenario 1
- Persona 1 | Scenario 2
- Persona 2 | Scenario 3

or should we have different personas for each CJM like:

- Persona 1 | Scenario 1
- Persona 2 | Scenario 2
- Persona 3 | Scenario 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, one personas can have several scenarios, and CJM are differente for personas/scenarios. For example, if you sell laptop you could have this 2 personas:

- geek: a person who works with computers and have specific technical needs
- dad: he needs to use pc only to browse internet, email and watch some films.

These 2 personas have different needs and goals so their CJM are different. We could identified 2 main scenario (this is only an example)

- looking for the right laptop
- buying the lapto
- setting the laptop the first time

Both of them have these 3 scenarios, but they are different for each personas.

So, IMO, you have a situation like this to build CJM:
 - looking for the right laptop - GEEK
 - looking for the right laptop - DAD

- buying the laptop - GEEK
- buying the laptop - DAD
- setting the laptop the first time - GEEK
- setting the laptop the first time - DAD

Answer (score 0):

[Personae are characterisations of different sets of user needs/goals based on ideal business customers](https://theuxreview.co.uk/personas-the-beginners-guide/).

[Scenarios are different workflows that lead to completing business goals](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/garage/content/think/practice_scenario_mapping/).

The two things are not exclusive to each other - You may have fewer personae than scenarios or you may have fewer scenario than personae. You may have a few personae that complete the same scenario or you may have one or two personae that complete several scenarios